# Compile directory containing java classes and text files using code

Tags: java, compilation

I've been looking around for days trying to find a way to compile a whole directory that doesn't only contain Java classes. I've got no idea how to add text files and dependency to the compiling process. Does someone know a way to do that? I know JavaCompiler is a thing but I can't get it to do that. I'd really appreciate it if anyone could send me some sample code using anything able to do what I want.

Comment: If you are doing this programatically in Java, you should use a `FileVisitor` to get a list of files that match (say) `*.java` and the pass that list to `JavaCompiler`.  (Sorry.  Not writing sample code for you.)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to compile the java files in a directory/folder, you can open a terminal , go to the specific folder and run

```
javac *.java
```

If you want to do this from your java application, you can use the Runtime class to execute operating system commands from your java program.

For example you can create a bash script or .bat file, put there all your commands, and then call

```
Runtime run = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process process=runtime.exec("Compile.bat");
```

You could also create a pom.xml, and use maven to build your project (by calling maven from you application)

Comment: I've got this right now but it doesn't seem to work as the class won't compile because of dependency not used in the compiling process: javac -cp ".;C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Test\jars\\*" -sourcepath ".;C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Test\resources\\*" C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Test\com\test\Main.java C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Test\com\test\Test.java